# How do I access my app scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I work for a university which uses Google App for EDU.  Recently, I decided to begin testing app script to see how it could be of use to our organization.  I have been able to create new app scripts and run them without issue.  However, I have found that once I close the browser editor tab, I am not able to retrieve any script I've wrote unless I have the editor url saved (ie. I dont see any of my script in my google drive).  Is there a particular app script site where my scripts are listed?

Thanks,

Bryan

Answer (score 3):

The long method i use to get to see all my App Scripts is:

1. open an existing spreadsheet, or simply create a new spreadsheet
2. go to Extensions > Apps Script
3. click on the "Apps Script" logo in the top left corner

This will take you to: https://script.google.com/home

The short method is just to have that link (above) saved on browser toolbar and click it whenever i need to.

Comment: Thanks! Wow, that seems so obvious but I naturally figured clicking the home logo would have just kept me on the AppScript starter page I was on. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

to be able to starts new script from the drive you have to connect script app to your drive using the Browser interface like below :

[image]

from the `connect more apps` at the bottom search for "`script`" and add it.

Answer (score 1):

If you created scripts from inside a spreadsheet, they are tied to that sheet and will not show up in Drive; you can find them via the "Script Manager" menu in that spreadsheet.

Comment: Where is the Script Manager menu? Does it still exist?

Answer (score 0):

All standalone scripts will be visible in your Google Drive. Did you write your script inside a spreadsheet or a Google Site ? If so, you have to open the spreadsheet or site to see your script.

If you indeed have a standalone script, make sure you click the 'All Items' on the left hand side of Google Drive or use search.

Comment: If you scripts are standalone, then you can copy the following and paste into your Drive search     type:application/vnd.google-apps.script

Comment: script was written apart from any google doc using the script editor started at script.google.com. @davidtew running the drive search returns "None of your Google Docs, files or folders matched this search."

Answer (score 0):

If you've created a new script from script.google.com and have saved it, it'll appear in Drive under the root My Drive folder.

If you created one from inside of Drive by clicking the red Create button then Script, it'll be in the folder which you last clicked on before clicking Create.  If you don't remember what folder you created the script file under, click the Recent folder name to find it.

If you've started one inside a Form , Sheet, or Doc you'll have to remember where the Form, Sheet or Doc was located in Drive.

Comment: I created the script in the script edit was started while on the script.google.com site.  Infact, I dont see any option to create a script by clicking the red "create" button in google drive.  There is no sign of any scripts in my google drive.

Comment: If you're sure you saved it, sounds like it might have been created under another Google account.

Answer (score 0):

You can search all your scripts in Google Drive using `app:"Google Apps Script"` or by selecting Google Apps Script under Opens With from the drop down menu.

As pointed out by @Mandy, this assumes you have added Apps Script as a connect app. See answer from @Serge on how to do that.

Comment: There is no option for opens with Google Apps Script on mine. Only Google Docs, Google Drawings, Google Forms, Google Sheets, Google Slides.

Comment: For those who have the same issue I did, you have to "enable" it first. Go to the normal drive menu and create new button. If Google Apps Scripts does not show, click "Connect more apps" and search for script, and add the Google Scripts there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the handy dashboard/central location for scripts:

https://script.google.com